# Database table not showing data after inner join

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, sqlconnection

I have a C# windows forms application and I'm working with a database too.
I have 3 tables: `Players`, `Tournaments` and `TournamentsPlayers`.

I will only show 2 tables in the form, the `Tournaments` and the `Players` tables. The `Tournaments` table has a column which is a checkbox and I want to show in the `Players` table only the players from the tournaments which I checked the box.

When the application starts I have a foreach statement which check all the tournaments, so at first all the players should show in the `Players` table, but no player is shown.

My code is:

```
private void ShowPlayersForSelectedTournaments()
        {
            string query =
                "SELECT a.Name, a.Id FROM Players a,TournamentPlayers b WHERE a.Id=b.TournamentId AND b.TournamentId=@TournamentId";
            using (Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TournamentsTable.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells.Count > 0 && bool.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TournamentId", row.Cells[1].Value);
                        DataTable tournamentPlayersList = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(tournamentPlayersList);
                        PlayersTable.DataSource = tournamentPlayersList;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried a simple select and all is working, but with this sql syntax it doesn't seems to work.
I have tried with another similar mysql syntax, like:

```
string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Players a INNER JOIN TournamentPlayers b ON a.Id=b.TournamentId WHERE b.TournamentId=@TournamentId";
```

But still nothing shows in the `Players` table.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my mysql syntax or my code?

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Doesn't seem right that `players.id = b.tournamentid` but you haven't shown your exact database structure.

Comment: a.ID is the id of a Player and you are relating it to a TournamentID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Id
FROM Players a,TournamentPlayers b
WHERE a.Id=b.TournamentId AND b.TournamentId=@TournamentId;
```

It has multiple problems.  This should work:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Id
FROM Players p JOIN
     TournamentPlayers tp
     ON tp.playerId = p.id
 WHERE tp.TournamentId = @TournamentId;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use abbreviations for the table names, so the query makes sense when read.
- FIx the join condition between the tables, to match on the player.  It is highly unlikely that a player has the same id as a tournament *and* also played in that tournament.  Possible, but unlikely.